# Git keep asking for password

Tags: git, ssh

Firstly, I'm seeking for this on internet (and, of course, in stackoverflow) at least for 6 hours... So please, do not give paleative solutions...

I'm configuring a new workstation to work with my git repository (not hosted on github).

On the server, my authorized_keys has others public keys (from others workstations of my team) and it already works fine.

On my new workstation, I create my id_rsa and id_rsa.pub (ssh-keygen), properly. After, I appended the id_rsa.pub's content on my authorized_keys.

But, always when I want to execute some git command, it ask me for password (like it has no ssh key installed).
At the first time I tryed, they (my git) ask me something like "you want to trust in server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx? Yes/No... " and "The footprint is XX:XX:XX...", and I chose "Yes" (of course), But the server persist to ask for damn password.

In a desperate act, I did the follow:
I create one user with same name that one of my other computers on my workgroup.
I did ssh-keygen again.
I overwirte my id_rsa files by his (other pc's team) id_rsa files and tryed again... but with no success...

Could anyone give some tip?
I think it isn't any problem on server (it works fine for other users).

Extra:

My git repo url is something like: ssh://user@domain.com/~/.git (and my git folder is on user's base dir). Again: This url works for others users.
I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Others computers are on Windows/Ubuntu mixed.
My server is on a remote web server (so, I dont't have sudo permitions, if you ask)
My git version is 1.9.1

PS: Sorry for my poor english skills...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful 
-[Caching Password (even if it is for GitHub, should work with GitLab and so on too)](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)
-[Skip password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)